# DAX formula (EVALUATE, FILTER, CALCULATETABLE and IN) issues

Tags: dax, evaluate

everybody! Please help to fix issues with following DAX formula. My last filer is by CU. Here I filter 301054. But i need several codes, so I want to use IN formula instead of using "=" condition. But when at the end of the code I type "'DIM Product2'[CU] in {301054, 000001, 000002}" my DAX query results in error. How should I use IN formula here properly?

Please help with fixing my code.

```
EVALUATE
FILTER (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                PLAN_Budget,
                'DIM Address2'[ClientClass],
                'Version'[OperationEng],
                'DIM Address2'[SellerRegionalDir],
                'DIM Address2'[SellerName],
                'DIM Product2'[CU],
                'DIM Date2'[Date]
            ),
            "Plan", [Plan tn]
        ),
        DATESBETWEEN ( 'DIM Date2'[Date], DATE ( 2018, 12, 10 ), DATE ( 2019, 02, 10 ) )
    ),
    [Plan] <> 0
        && 'Version'[OperationEng] = "6NP"
        && ( 'DIM Address2'[ClientClass] = "Первичные продажи" )
        && 'DIM Product2'[CU] = 301054
)
```

Comment: Could you share the error message?

Comment: what software versions do you use?

Comment: @Rory Thanks for your answer! My error message is following:  "Query (1,434) Неверный синтаксис in." Sorry for Russian language( Nevertheless I have english version of MS Office, the text error appears in Russian).

Comment: @RADO Excel 2010 with Power Pivot add-in. Both Excel and add-in are 64-bit. Does this matter? Should I ask Service Desk to install 2016 office (365 I am right)? I think there won't be any problem.

Comment: That's the source of your problem. Operator "IN" in dax works only in Excel 2016 or later. Regradless, you should switch to 2016 as soon as possible, because the difference from Excel 2010 is huge. Удачи!

Comment: @RADO Thank you very much! Now asking Service Desk for install MS Office 2016 on my computer.